# SQL SELECT FIELDS IN A DIFFERENT TABLE

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one called orders and the other one is invoices. I want to know if I have a closed order without an invoice.  they're joined by id_order, so I have this.

```
select  I.ID_Order,O.ID_order from Invoices I
inner join Orders O on o.ID_Order = I.ID_Order
where o.Status='x'
```

if o.iD_order is found in invoices that means the order is invoiced.
if o.id_order is not found in invoices that means its not invoiced.

I want to get in the select statement all of the orders that are not invoiced.

Answer (score 0):

Method1:

```
select *  
From Order 
Where ID_Order not in (Select ID_Order from Invoices)
```

Method 2:

```
select  O.*
from Orders O 
Left join
Invoices I
on o.ID_Order = I.ID_Order
where I.ID_Order IS NULL
```

Method 3:

```
select * 
From Order as O
Where Not Exists (Select ID_Order from Invoices as I Where I.ID_Order = O.ID_Order)
```

Stick to the first one, usually that has a better performance.

Comment: I'm new to sql and I don't know how I didn't see this. it worked, thank you.

Comment: not a problem xD @taby, just updated you with two more methods if you are trying to use `join`